# Perl parsing white space char at end of string

Tags: perl, parsing

```
MMAPI_CLOCK_OUTPUTS = 1,        /*clock outputs system*/
```

parsing the above with this:

```
$TheLine =~ /\s*(.*)\s*=\s*(.*),\s*\/\*(.*)\*\//)
```

The variable `$1` contains white space at the end, e.g. we have `"MMAPI_CLOCK_OUTPUTS "` and not `"MMAPI_CLOCK_OUTPUTS"`. Why are those spaces captured as well? I thought they should have be removed with the parser code

Answer (score 8):

The regex capture `(.*)` is a *greedy* match, meaning it will match as many characters as possible. Since the following `\s*` can be zero-length, the preceding string *including a space* is included in the capture.

Change it to a non-greedy patern by adding a question mark  `(.*?)`, and use a different delimiter to avoid having to escape the slashes in the pattern

```
$TheLine =~ m<\s*(.*?)\s*=\s*(.*),\s*/\*(.*)\*/>
```

Comment: Learnt something new today, +1

Answer (score 1):

TIMTOWTDI, or "I haven't used [Regexp::Grammars](http://p3rl.org/Regexp%3a%3aGrammars) in a while"

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Grammars;
my $parser = qr{
  <nocontext:>

  <Definitions>

  <rule: Definitions>   <[Definition]>*
  <rule: Definition>    <Variable> = <Value>
  <rule: Variable>  <Word>
  <rule: Value>     <Word>
  <rule: Word>      [\w\d_]+
}xms;

my $str = 'MMAPI_CLOCK_OUTPUTS = 1,        /*clock outputs system*/';

$str =~ $parser;

# see the whole matched structure
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%/; 

# or walk the structure for results
for my $def (@{ $/{Definitions}{Definition} }) {
  print $def->{Variable}{Word} . ' => ' . $def->{Value}{Word} . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the word before `=` sign doesn't have spaces in it, change `(.*)` to `(\S+)`

```
$TheLine =~ /\s*(\S+)\s*=\s*(.*),\s*\/\*(.*)\*\//)
           here __^
```

Comment: We haven't been told that the label before the `=` cannot contain whitespace